# Using join with more than one clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to load a list of entities, with 2 conditions which I'm passing with a list of `Tuple`. See:

```
private IEnumerable<Invoice> FindInvoices(IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> vars) { ... }
```

Now, I'm having truble to how to join the main entity-set with the input parameters:

```
private IEnumerable<Invoice> FindInvoices(IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> vars) {
    var q = from i in context.Invoices
            join v in vars on 
                i.Prop1 == v.Item1
                // HERE IS THE PROBLEM. THERE IS NO "&&" or "and" to apply:
                && i.Prop2 == v.Item2
}
```

As you can see, since there is no `&&` or `and` support, I cannot apply the second condition to clause. So, how can I write a `join` with 2 conditions in `on` clause?

OR can you suggest any alternative? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im not sure if this applies to entity framework as well. if it doesn't, my apologies. please let me know so i will retract my vote.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks the comment. I found the join answer, but I'm not sure too if it works in linq2ef or not. Ill let you know the result of test.